# JAVA : How make custom inner class for complex Json

Tags: java, json, jackson

I've read a lot posts but don't find how make the class for this json.

```
{
    "snippet": {
        "parentGroupId": "69ea5920-0157-1000-0000-0000028e1b90",
        "processors": {},
        "processGroups": {
            "1231-23a": {
                "clientId": "50b3ec1a-c123-1e4f-718c-b0323fb1e175",
                "version": 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the problem is that property "1231-23a" can change in my json like this :

```
{
    "snippet": {
        "parentGroupId": "69ea5920-0157-1000-0000-0000028e1b90",
        "processors": {},
        "processGroups": {
            "4544-412f": {
                "clientId": "50b3ec1a-c123-1e4f-718c-b0323fb1e175",
                "version": 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

thanks for yours helps

Comment: Can the processGroups attribute have many children, or only ever one?

Comment: processGroups has only one children

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Map` from `String` to the nested data for example `ProcessGroup`. Then `"1231-23a"` and "4544-412f" would be keys in this `Map`. For example these classes for `"snippet"` and `"processGroups"` and add constructors, getters etc

```
class Snippet {
    String parentGroupId;
    Processors processors;
    Map<String, ProcessGroup> processGroups;
}


class ProcessGroup {
    String clientId;
    int version;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@manos,

It's missing in my classes to work correctly.

**snippet**

```
class Snippet {
    String parentGroupId;
//    Processors processors;
    Map<String, ProcessGroup> processGroups;

    public void setParentGroupId(String string) {

        this.parentGroupId = string ;

    }

    public void setProcessGroups(Map<String, ProcessGroup> procGps)
    {
        this.processGroups = procGps;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String str = "{\n"
                + "   \"snippet\": {\n"
                +"     \"parentGroupId\": \""+ this.parentGroupId      +"\",\n"
                +"     \"processGroups\": \""+ this.processGroups +"\""
                + "\n}";
        return str;
    }

}
```

**ProcessGroup class**

```
class ProcessGroup {
    String clientId;
    int version;

    public void setClientId(String clientId) {
        this.clientId = clientId; 

    }

    public void setVersion(int version) {
        this.version = version;

    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String str = "\n    \"clientId\": \"" + this.clientId +"\"\n "
                    +"  \"version\": "+ this.version;
        return str;
    }
}
```

**Test class**

```
public class Test {

       public static void main(String[] args) {

            Map<String, ProcessGroup> map = new HashMap<String, ProcessGroup>();


           // ObjectMapper oMapper = new ObjectMapper();

            //Student obj = new Student();
            Snippet obj = new Snippet();
            ProcessGroup objPG = new ProcessGroup();

            objPG.setClientId("clientId-10");
            objPG.setVersion(12);

            obj.setParentGroupId("parentId-10");

            map.put("processGroup-10", objPG);

            obj.setProcessGroups(map);

            // object -> Map

            System.out.println(obj);

        }

}
```

**result**

it seems, i don't have 'access' to processGroup-10 and plus the sign "=" and not ":"
What's wrong ?

```
{
 "snippet": {
  "parentGroupId": "parentId-10",
  "processGroups": "{processGroup-10=
 "clientId": "clientId-10"
 "version": 12}"
}
```